# Armed only one JMenuItem of a JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jpopupmenu

I have a JPopupMenu that every time I write it is updated. And by default, the first element is armed. I want to be able to use the up and down keys to be able to select the different JMenuItem.

```
public void colocar(Component e, int x, int y, ArrayList<Ocurrencia> predicciones) {
    this.Pmenu.setVisible(false);
    this.Pmenu.removeAll();

    JMenuItem menuItem;
    for (int i = 0; i < predicciones.size(); i++) {
        menuItem = new JMenuItem(predicciones.get(i).getPrediccion());
        Pmenu.add(menuItem);
        if (i == 0) {
            menuItem.setArmed(true);
        }
        menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListenerImpl(jt));
    }

    this.Pmenu.show(e, x, y);
    this.jt.requestFocus();
}
```

By means of a listener I control the keyCode pressed to know if it is the 38 or 40, (key up or down). I save all the components in an array and then I try to use .setArmed (true) but it does not change. I wanted to ask if for armed that JMenuItem there is any way other than to delete all the JMenuItem and re-insert them with the one I want armed.

This is the complete class:

public class PopUpMenu {

```
private final JPopupMenu Pmenu;
private final javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea;

public PopUpMenu(javax.swing.JTextArea jt, JPopupMenu Pm) {
    this.jTextArea = jt;
    Pmenu = Pm;
}

public void colocar(Component e, int x, int y, ArrayList<Ocurrencia> predicciones) {
    this.Pmenu.setVisible(false);
    this.Pmenu.removeAll();

    JMenuItem menuItem;
    for (int i = 0; i < predicciones.size(); i++) {
        Pmenu.add(menuItem = new JMenuItem(predicciones.get(i).getPrediccion()));
        menuItem.setHorizontalTextPosition(JMenuItem.RIGHT);
        menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListenerImpl(jTextArea));
    }

    this.Pmenu.show(e, x, y);
    this.jTextArea.requestFocus();
}

private static class ActionListenerImpl implements ActionListener {

    private final javax.swing.JTextArea jt;

    public ActionListenerImpl(javax.swing.JTextArea jt) {
        this.jt = jt;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(jt.getText());

        String semilla = jt.getText().substring(0, jt.getCaretPosition());

        String[] palabras = semilla.split("\\s+");
        String palabraInacabada = palabras[palabras.length - 1];
        String prediccionRecortada = e.getActionCommand().substring(palabraInacabada.length(), e.getActionCommand().length());

        sb.insert(jt.getCaretPosition(), prediccionRecortada + " ");

        jt.setText(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please explain, what you want to achive. Usually JPopupMenu automatically supports up/down keys. Also it would be nice if you post a short runnable example([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we also can run and debug it.

Comment: Why are you using `setArmed(...)`. That is really an internal state of the component and not something the application generally plays with. There is no need to do that. Just add an ActionListener to the menu item.

Comment: To try to have the first item armed. I tried but the up and down keys do not work and I do not understand why. I have tried other projects and I do the same ....